# Input data in tabular format as opposed to a textarea for form submit

Tags: html, forms, input, textarea

At present I have a form with a textarea. The data in the textarea needs to be comma separated:

TEXTAREA:
John,21,New York,Engineer
Pete,44,London,Doctor
Jane,34,Tokyo,manager

[SUBMIT]

What would be the easiest way to replace the textarea with tabular input so that the user can input the data into cells rather than having to enter the data as CSV text?:

| NAME | AGE | LOCATION | EMPLOYMENT |
| John | 21  | New York | Engineer   |
| Pete | 44  | London   | Doctor     |
| Jane | 34  | Tokyo    | manager    |

[SUBMIT]

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: The question is: how can data be inputted by a user in a tabular format within a form? I would like to replace the current textarea which requires users to input the data as CSV and replace it with something more user friendly that looks and feels more like inputting data into excel. I think I may need to make use of the datatables plugin for jQuery? Any advice?